# Run a Local Shell Script on a Remote SSH Server, but the script requires env variables from another local file

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I want to run a local bash script on a remote machine to install and sets up dokku and its plugins. (`ssh root@remotehost 'bash -s' < dokku.sh`) The script requires a few config values like `AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS` etc. Those variables are stored in a separate json file, like this:

/home/project/env.json

```
{
  "DB_NAME": "mydb",
  "APP_NAME": "web",
  "AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS": "xxx",
  "AWS_BACKUP_SECRET": "yyy",
}
```

dokku.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

json_file="/home/project/env.json"
# export all key values from env.json to globa env
for s in $(cat $json_file | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); do
    export $s;
done

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.25.7/bootstrap.sh;
sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.25.7 bash bootstrap.sh
sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres.git postgres
dokku postgres:create "$DB_NAME"
dokku postgres:link "$DB_NAME" "$APP_NAME"
# use the Backup IAM profile
dokku postgres:backup-auth "$DB_NAME" "$AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS" "$AWS_BACKUP_SECRET" "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
```

My question is how to make the following part works when running the script on a remote server since the file `/home/project/env.json` is stored locally:

```
json_file="/home/project/env.json"
# export all key values from env.json to globa env
for s in $(cat $json_file | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); do
    export $s;
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the JSON file locally, and then make the SSH connection.  This would additionally no longer require `jq` to be available on the remote system.

Your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -u -e

wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.25.7/bootstrap.sh'

sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.25.7 bash bootstrap.sh
sudo dokku plugin:install 'https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres.git' postgres

dokku postgres:create "$DB_NAME"
dokku postgres:link "$DB_NAME" "$APP_NAME"

# use the Backup IAM profile
dokku postgres:backup-auth \
    "$DB_NAME" \
    "$AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS" \
    "$AWS_BACKUP_SECRET" \
    "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
```

Running it:

```bsh
ssh root@remotehost "env $( jq -r 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | @sh' /home/project/env.json ) sh -s" <dokku.sh
```

This calls `env` on the remote system, with a list of environment variables and their values as arguments.  At the end of the argument list is `sh -s` which will read your `dokku.sh` script and execute it (the script uses no bashisms, so there's no need to invoke a more advanced shell).

I'm also using `set -u` in the script to make it terminate if it encounters an unset variable, and `set -e` to terminate on any error.

You could obviously wrap the `ssh`-calling bit in a local script, or use something like Ansible to do the whole thing more reliably.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just `scp` the env.json file from the local machine to the remote, use it in your script, and delete it afterwards.

Alternatively, you can write a script that sets/exports the variables it needs, and `scp` the script to the remote server before running it.

In fact, a lot of PITA problems with `ssh` involving quoting and white-space and variables can be eliminated just by `scp`-ing a script and/or data files to the remote server and running the script instead of trying to do it in a one-liner with multiple levels of nested quoting.

Note that it's pretty common for `sshd` to be configured with `PermitUserEnvironment no` (it's usually compiled in as one of sshd's default settings), so the user's environment is not passed from the client machine to the ssh server.   So setting the env vars on your local machine is not likely to work.

Comment: BTW, if you need to do things like this on lots of machines, you should probably look into tools like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com), [puppet](https://puppet.com/), or [chef](https://www.chef.io/)